# Duplicates in Database, Help Edit My Query to Filter Them Out?

Tags: mysql, distinct, distinct-values

I have just finished my latest task of creating an RSS Feed using PHP to fetch data from a database.

I've only just noticed that a lot (if not all) of these items have duplicates and I was trying to work out how to only fetch one of each.

I had a thought that in my PHP loop I could only print out every second row to only have one of each set of duplicates but in some cases there are 3 or 4 of each article so somehow it must be achieved by the query.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM uk_newsreach_article t1
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_article_photo t2
        ON t1.id = t2.newsArticleID
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_photo t3
        ON t2.newsPhotoID = t3.id
ORDER BY t1.publishDate DESC;
```

**Table Structures:**

```
uk_newsreach_article
--------------------
id | headline | extract | text | publishDate | ...

uk_newsreach_article_photo
--------------------------
id | newsArticleID | newsPhotoID

uk_newsreach_photo
------------------
id | htmlAlt | URL | height | width | ...
```

For some reason or another there are lots of duplicates and the only thing truely unique amongst each set of data is the `uk_newsreach_article_photo.id` because even though `uk_newsreach_article_photo.newsArticleID` and `uk_newsreach_article_photo.newsPhotoID` are identical in a set of duplicates, all I need is one from each set, e.g.

**Sample Data**

```
id | newsArticleID | newsPhotoID
--------------------------------
 2 |     800482746 |     7044521
10 |     800482746 |     7044521
19 |     800482746 |     7044521
29 |     800482746 |     7044521
39 |     800482746 |     7044521
53 |     800482746 |     7044521
67 |     800482746 |     7044521
```

I tried sticking a `DISTINCT` into the query along with specifying the actual columns I wanted but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, the `DISTINCT` operator will return every id. You could use a `GROUP BY`instead.

You will have to make a decision about wich `id` you want to retain. In the example, I have used `MIN`but any aggregate function would do.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT MIN(t1.id), t2.newsArticleID, t2.newsPhotoID 
FROM uk_newsreach_article t1
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_article_photo t2
        ON t1.id = t2.newsArticleID
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_photo t3
        ON t2.newsPhotoID = t3.id
GROUP BY t2.newsArticleID, t2.newsPhotoID 
ORDER BY t1.publishDate DESC;
```

#### Disclaimer

Now while this would be an easy solution to your immediate problem, if you decide that duplicates *should not* happen, you really should consider redesigning your tables to prevent duplicates getting into your tables in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I will try this and report back. I'm afraid these tables were designed long before I joined the company so I don't think they will ever be redesigned!

Comment: just tried out your query, getting an error saying `SQL Errir (1052): Colum 'id' in field list is ambiguos` I tried adding in the table name to each column but it complained about that too. Also, I need a lot more columns than these 3 ids, this is just the root of the problem but I don't think adding more columns to the select will be a problem once this is fixed?

Comment: @martincarling87 - I have added the table aliases to the query but by doing so, I've noticed you've joined `t1.id` on `t2.newsArticleID`. If that is correct, this can never give the output you've shown us. In your output, the `id`'s are different from the `newsArticleID`'s.

Comment: @martincarlin87 - It will not be an unsolvable problem but you might need to turn this query into a subselect or just add the additional columns to the GROUP BY statement. Wich one, we can only know once we know all your in- and outputs.

Comment: sorry, I think I might have used the wrong term, the actual output is about 45 columns and some rows are duplicates and the only thing that differentiates between them is the `id` from the `uk_newsreach_article` table. The output in my question was to highlight that to solve this the query would need to focus on that table, so really the data in my question is just a subset of data inside that table, hope that makes sense :S

Comment: just ran your query and I don't think there's any duplicates which is great, thank you! Only thing I need is to get all the other columns back now aside from just these 3 id's.

Comment: @martincarlin87 - It  makes sense enough but it doesn't alter the fact that right now, only *you* can know if you need to wrap this into a subselect or if you can get away with adding additional columns to the group by :)

Comment: Thanks, if I try `GROUP BY t1.id, t1.headline, t1.extract, t2.id, t2.newsArticleID, t2.newsPhotoID` I am still only getting the 3 columns, any idea how to fix this? (Almost there!)

Comment: @martincarlin87 - You also need to add the extra columns to your select statement. For all intents and purposes, only those columns between `SELECT` and `FROM` will be returned in a result set.

Comment: ah, thank you so much, I should be able to do what I want from here. Time to read up more on mysql I think!

Comment: @martincarlin87 - Indeed. Expect a whole new world to open, full of wonders (and sometimes frustrations) <g>.

Answer (score 1):

`group by` all your selected columns with `HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1` will eleminate all duplicates like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM uk_newsreach_article t1
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_article_photo t2
      ON t1.id = t2.newsArticleID
    INNER JOIN uk_newsreach_photo t3
      ON t2.newsPhotoID = t3.id
GROUP BY  t1.id, t1.headline, t1.extract, t1.text, t1.publishDate,
          t2.id, t2.newsArticleID, t2.newsPhotoID,
          t3.id, t3.htmlAlt, t3.URL, t3.height, t3.width
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY t1.publishDate DESC;
```

Comment: ah, getting this error: `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near 'GROUP BY t1.id, t1.headline, t2.id HAVING COUNT (*) > 1' at line 1` . In your `GROUP BY` I just put `t1.id, t1.headline, t2.id` as a test for just now.

Comment: No you have to put all your selected columns i just wrote it like that becouse i didn't want to list all of them put you need to list all

Comment: @martincarlin87 ,I Edited my answer, it shoul work like this it might be strange to put all these columns in the `group by` statement but this is the only way to make it work.

Comment: thanks again, I really appreciate it. It really doesn't like all those columns being in the `GROUP BY` clause though. :(

Comment: @martincarlin87 Sorry for all of that, the `Order by` clouse must be after the group by and having cloused try me last edit, and waiting for your review, Sorry again.

Comment: no problem, thanks very much for helping. I got Lieven's query to work but will try yours too. Thanks

Comment: The point is you should got an answer, Whatever whose answer. :)